# Graph call to change planner task returning 204 (and not making the change)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using python to make calls to the Graph API regarding planner and tasks. whenever I use PATCH to try and update the task I get a 204 response back and the task remains unchanged. According to Microsoft's documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/plannertask-update?view=graph-rest-1.0#feedback), this request should always return either a 200, or a 400 level error.

I have tried changing the data that I send to the server, to change the title rather than the dates, however I get the same 204 response no matter what data I send or what field I attempt to change. I have no problem making other graph calls like updating files in One Drive or getting data about a user

```
def SetDates(task):
    '''Update planner to match the start date and due date of the passed in task'''
    tid = task["id"]
    start = task["startDateTime"]    
    end = task["dueDateTime"] 
    newDates = {"dueDateTime": end,"startDateTime": start}    
    etag = task["@odata.etag"]
    session.headers.update({'If-Match':etag})
    response = session.patch(f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks/{tid}", data = newDates)
    session.headers.pop('If-Match')
    print(task["title"] + " Has been scheduled")
```

Based on the documentation I expect this to return a status code of 200, and for the response to contain the data of the task that was updated, and for the change to actually be applied to the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally figured this out.
@Tarken Sevilmis mentioned that in order to get a 200 response from a PATCH request you need to add

```
Prefer: return=representation
```

to your request. In my case the reason that my changes weren't being applied was because I hadn't set the content type in the header. The Graph API didn't give an error, but this seems to have been the cause of the issue. Once I set the content type to application/json it gave a proper error indication that the values I gave in the body weren't being read correctly, and I realized that I forgot to parse them to JSON.

Once you set the content headers appropriately and make sure to convert your data to proper JSON everything should work as intended

Answer (score 1):

By default, PATCH requests return an empty response with 204 return code. To get the data updated data back, you should send "Prefer" HTTP header with value "return=representation".

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks/{task-id}
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 247
If-Match: W/"JzEtVGFzayAgQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAWCc="
Prefer: return=representation
```

Comment: Thanks, that does cause it to return the task back to me, however the changes still aren't actually being applied. Do you have any idea why that may be?